# Handle EntityCommandExecutionException and show error message

Tags: wpf, linq, sql-server-2008, ado.net, entity-framework-6

When I make a change in the database (add, delete, rename a column) and don't update my `EF` mappings, I get an exception while in debug mode

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException

but I don't see this exception caught in the Global `DispatcherUnhandledException` even if I catch and throw it from the code where the exception is occuring. What is the reason? Basically I want to validate my `EF` mappings when my application loads and if there is any mismatch in mapping I want to show user a friendly message that **Client Application needs to be updated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to create a command interceptor. This concept was introduced in Entity Framework 6.0.

You create the interceptor by implementing the [IDbCommandInterceptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.interception.idbcommandinterceptor(v=vs.113).aspx) interface and then register it either through code or configuration.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_command_interception.htm

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/connection-resiliency-and-command-interception-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application